# Cross-region replica DynamoDB transaction conflict handling

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Since transactions are only ACID in a single region, and don't replicate until said region completes the transaction, there is opportunity for transactions to occur simultaneously in different regions which would not be allowed to happen in the same region, then when these transactions replicate to other regions, they cannot be completed because of some condition.

Example:

User 1 buys item 1 from User 2 in region A

User 3 buys item 1 from User 2 in region B at the same time

Region A transaction completes, Region B transaction completes, and both begin to replicate to the other regions. Transaction 1 cannot complete in region B, and Transaction 2 cannot complete in region A, because User 2 no longer has that item (it now belongs to User 1 and User 3 respectively).

How does DynamoDB handle these conflicts? SQL DBs would typically prevent this because of the single Writer node, but since DynamoDB has multiple writer nodes we can see this potential conflict.

Answer (score 2):

Once the transaction is complete in a region, the item changes individually enter the stream to be replicated via global tables, not the transaction. The transaction is over.

In your scenario, DynamoDB's conflict resolution works as it normally does on each individual item. DynamoDB uses last writer wins for its conflict resolution.